# View from Activity in external service

Tags: java, android

I have servic(external it is not "startService()" nor "bindService()") and an Activity which is another  app. I need to find Linearlayout from Activity. How can I get context of Activity in my service? becasue now I did:

```
LLExt ll = (LLExt)findViewById(R.id.llBackGround);
```

and llbackGround is in aar in libs folder. But when I am debugging I have only null all the time. It is some kind of way to get this view not null?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? You cannot get the view/activity of another app

Comment: so is no way to make it work? I need this view in my service :(

Comment: Your service cannot and should not be directly talking to your UI